# CMake: SOVERSION and Mac library id in shared library made from assembly files

Tags: assembly, cmake, shared-libraries, versioning

I have a little project that creates a shared library from a pair of assembly files. I've been trying to follow examples such that the generated library

- has versioning (libFastCompression.1.dylib on Mac or libFastCompression.so.1 on Linux)
- has the full path as its ID on Mac

Specifically, my CMakeLists.txt has:

```
project(lzvn LANGUAGES C ASM VERSION 1.0.0)
set(lzvn_FULL_VERSION "${lzvn_VERSION_MAJOR}.${lzvn_VERSION_MINOR}.${lzvn_VERSION_PATCH}")
# snip
add_library(FastCompression SHARED lzvn_decode.S lzvn_encode.S)
set_target_properties(FastCompression PROPERTIES
    VERSION ${lzvn_FULL_VERSION_MAJOR}.${lzvn_VERSION_MINOR}
    SOVERSION ${lzvn_VERSION_MAJOR})
```

That works in the projects I used as example, but not in this particular project. There I just get a libFastCompression.dylib (or .so) file, and on Mac the library ID does not contain any path info at all.

Am I overlooking/forgetting something, or is what I'm looking for not implemented/supported (in CMake) for libraries built exclusively from assembly files?

The project: [github.com/RJVB/lzvn](http://github.com/RJVB/lzvn)

Thanks!

René

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `LINKER_LANGUAGE` property to your target with value `C`. That results in the following link command for me: (on Ubuntu at least, don't have a Mac handy)

```
/usr/bin/cc -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libFastCompression.so.1 -o libFastCompression.so.4.0 CMakeFiles/FastCompression.dir/lzvn_decode.S.o CMakeFiles/FastCompression.dir/lzvn_encode.S.o
```

Comment: Looks like a CMake bug though, whether to use versioning or not should NOT depend on the languages used in the library - or should it?

Comment: The code seems to suggest it does: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/b1c8d95dbe97ab2511e08518bf8eee1f5da2e941/Source/cmGeneratorTarget.cxx#L1244

Comment: See also my bug report about it: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18366 . Apparently it's not illogical; cmake has to know how to set the attributes in question.